# Rails 6 API + ActiveStorage + Heroku + S3 - image urls not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

I have a Rails 6 API with a model `Property` that `has_many_attached :images`.

These images are attached to a model in `properties_controller#create`.  In order to return the image to the frontend, I send the `url_for(img)` for each image attached to a property.  ActiveStorage is configured to store the images in AWS S3 in both development and production (there are separate buckets for dev and prod).

In development, these urls look something like `"http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--126782dcd2003952f1ef243c596824576b86400a/avatar.png"`, and the images render in the browser (Chrome FWIW).

In production (API is deployed to Heroku), the urls look like `"https://the-heroku-project.com/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--7d05475d4afbf8e414c9b47ab85bbbaae4a12a8c/simpson_living_room.jpg"`.

However, in production, broken image links render, rather than the images themselves.  Pasting the URL in the browser behaves differently than locally -

- locally the url takes me to a page consisting only of the corresponding image
- in production, part of the webpage renders (background, a few other elements) - although the element (and broken image icon) that do render is not actually associated with the image src that I was trying to access...
  [image]

Any idea why the urls wouldn't work in production?

---

further investigation shows a difference between development and production:

development - redirect happens, url contains s3 bucket
[image]

production - no redirect, url contains project url, not s3 bucket
[image]

storage.yml =>

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

# Use rails credentials:edit to set the AWS secrets (as aws:access_key_id|secret_access_key)
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
  secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
  region: us-west-2
  bucket: bucketname-<%= Rails.env %>
```

Comment: Share your `storage.yml` and, btw, Heroku doesn't allow you to "write files" (even temporally) in their servers, this might be the issue...

Comment: @FábioAraújo any other thoughts?

Comment: Quick question, do you have in your `config/environment/production.rb` a line like this: `config.active_storage.service = :amazon`

Comment: @FábioAraújo I do, yea

Comment: Same issue here. Did you get any further on this?

Comment: Try using `img.url` instead of `url_for(img)`

Answer (score 0):

For Active Storage to be fully functional, it needs imagemagick library and libvip.
Did you add it to Heroku via an AptFile for e.g. ?
I had the same issue and it was the missing libraries that was causing the error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31366373)